# Database SSL error

Tags: python, database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy

I have a Python application that accesses a PostgreSQL database using SQLAlchemy. Today, at roughly 15 - 20 minute intervals I get an exception 
`#012DatabaseError: (DatabaseError) SSL error: wrong final block length#012` when my code reads from the database.

What would cause such an error? We're running on AWS and there doesn't appear to be any disruptions to AWS at the moment.